# NavigationDrawer not show the view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer with Navigation View, there are four tabs, one of them is a fragment, which includes ViewPager, ie is a host for the other fragments. Everything works fine, but when switched from fragment with ViewPager any other fragment of NavigationDrawer shows nothing. Checked logs, onCreate, onCreateView these fragments are called, but why does not display... Who knows why?

NavigationDrawer

```
public class NavigationDrawerHost extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
//буду использовать эту активность как хост под все фрагменты, чтобы верно работал мой drawer!

    public static String WHERE_FROM = NavigationDrawerHost.class.getSimpleName();

    public static Toolbar toolbar;
    public static ProgressBar progressBar;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private int navItemId;
    private static final String NAV_ITEM_ID = "NAV_ITEM_ID";

    private TextView userFirstNameTextView, userLastNameTextView;
    private ImageView userPhotoImageView;

    private VKAccessToken access_token; //токен это информация о правах доступа
    private VKApiUser user; //текущий пользователь

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_host);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // Find the toolbar view inside the activity layout
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //setTitle(R.string.drawer_menu_posts);

        // load saved navigation state if present
        if (null == savedInstanceState) {
            navItemId = R.id.posts_fragment;
        } else {
            navItemId = savedInstanceState.getInt(NAV_ITEM_ID);
        }

        // Find our drawer view
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // select the correct nav menu item
        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(navItemId).setChecked(true);

        // если хотим добавить какие-то элементы в наш header,
        // то нужно добавить их в layout, а затем инициализировать нижеприведенным способом
        // Inflate the header view at runtime
        View headerLayout = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
        // We can now look up items within the header if needed
        userFirstNameTextView = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.user_first_name);
        userLastNameTextView = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.user_last_name);
        userPhotoImageView = (ImageView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.user_photo);

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        drawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.syncState();

        selectItem(navItemId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(NAV_ITEM_ID, navItemId);
    }

    // Menu icons are inflated just as they were with actionbar
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_exit:
                //quitDialog();
                VKSdk.logout();
                finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // Make sure this is the method with just `Bundle` as the signature
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private void selectItem(final int itemId) {
        // perform the actual navigation logic, updating the main content fragment etc
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;

        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.posts_fragment:
                fragmentClass = PostsFragment.class;
                fragment = new PostsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.albums_fragment:
                fragmentClass = FragmentTest.class;
                fragment = new FragmentTest();
                break;
            case R.id.friends_fragment:
                fragmentClass = FragmentTest.class;
                fragment = new FragmentTest();
                break;
            case R.id.likes_fragment:
                fragmentClass = LikesFragment.class;
                fragment = new LikesFragment();
                break;
            /*default:
                fragmentClass = PostsFragment.class;*/
        }

        /*try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

        drawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        // update highlighted item in the navigation menu
        item.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(item.getTitle());
        navItemId = item.getItemId();

        // allow some time after closing the drawer before performing real navigation
        // so the user can see what is happening
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        selectItem(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            quitDialog();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }

    private void quitDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder quitDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        quitDialog.setTitle("Вы хотите выйти?");

        quitDialog.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //стираем БД
                Delete.tables(PostTable.class, PictureTable.class, PostTableMyLikes.class, PictureTableMyLikes.class);

                FlowManager.getDatabase(WallDatabase.DB_NAME).reset(NavigationDrawerHost.this);
                FlowManager.getDatabase(WallDatabaseMyLikes.DB_NAME).reset(NavigationDrawerHost.this);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        quitDialog.setNegativeButton("Нет",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

        quitDialog.show();
    }


}
```

ViewPager host for fragments, which needs to display through ViewPager

```
//этот фрагмент является хостом для MyLikesFragment и FriendLikesFragment, так же тут содержатся табы
public class LikesFragment extends Fragment {

    public static String WHERE_FROM_FRIENDS_LIKES = LikesFragment.class.getSimpleName() + "_FRIENDSLIKES";

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.likes_fragment, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Мои лайки"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Лайки друзей"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        viewPager.setAdapter(new LikesPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public static class LikesPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public LikesPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        //сделано так, чтобы передавать те аргументы, от которых будет зависеть функционал фрагмента
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return (position == 0) ? new MyLikesPostsFragment() : new PostsFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return (position == 0) ? "Мои лайки" : "Лайки друзей";
        }

    }

}
```

P.S. And after going to the same fragment ViewPager select several items in drawer, this should not be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in the main thread and `onPostExecute()` in AsyncTask. My carelessness...

Comment: now that problem is solve for you accept your answer so that it can be easy for future readers